# Based on the asymptotic limiting of random variable $X$, how to get the asymptotic upper bound of $\frac{1}{\log X}$?

Tags: probability, analysis, inequality

Given a random variable $X$ with its value larger than $1$, assume that for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a constant $C>0$ so that
$$
\lim_{N\to \infty} P(N(X-1)\ge C)\ge 1-\epsilon
$$
(i.e., $X=1+O_p(N^{-1})$)

I am working on prove that for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a constant $c>0$ so that
$$
\lim_{N\to \infty} P(\frac{1}{\log X}\le c N)\ge 1-\epsilon
$$

---

By our condition, we have that as $N\to \infty$,
$$
P(\frac{1}{\log X} \le \frac{1}{\log(1+CN^{-1})})\ge 1-\epsilon.
$$
However, I am stuck on this step. I try to apply the fact that $\frac{x}{1+x}\le \log (1+x)$, and then I can only get
$$
\frac{1}{\log(1+CN^{-1})}\le 1+C^{-1}N...
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $c = 2/C$ by using this inequality

$$\ln(1+x) > \frac{x}{2} \hspace{1cm} \forall x\in [0,1)$$

It suffices to study the function $f(x) = \ln(1+x) - x/2$ which is increasing for $x \in [0,1)$.